# y-axis labels on opposite sides in `facet_wrap`

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I would like to plot a `facet_wrap` of 2 groups, and have the y-axis labels on the left on the left plot, and the right on the right plot.

Here is the normal behavior. Both y-axis labels on the left.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% mutate(let = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = nrow(mtcars)/2),
                       make = rownames(mtcars))  %>% 
ggplot(aes(y = make, x = mpg)) + 
geom_point() +
facet_wrap(~ let, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would like to have the `B` plot y-axis labels on the right side of the plot, but keep the `A` axis labels on the left side of the plot. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to make two plots and use `patchwork` to combine them:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
quux <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    let = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = nrow(mtcars)/2),
    make = rownames(mtcars)
  )
gg1 <- filter(quux, let == "A") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = make, x = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ let, scales = "free")
gg2 <- filter(quux, let == "B") %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = make, x = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ let, scales = "free") +
  scale_y_discrete(position = "right")

library(patchwork)
gg1 + gg2
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted this solution because patchwork is already part of my workflow, even though it requires more lines of code than the previous `ggh4x` solution.

Answer (score 5):

One option is the `ggh4x` package which via `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` allows to individually set the scales for each panel:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(ggh4x)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(
    let = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = nrow(mtcars) / 2),
    make = rownames(mtcars)
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = make, x = mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~let, scales = "free") +
  facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      let == "B" ~ scale_y_discrete(position = "right")
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I was unaware of the `ggh4x` package, this solution works great!